# HTML5 Video in Chrome not working under mp4

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple site to display a video on a canvas.  The video displays but it just is stuck at the first frame, I have controls set and autoplay neither show up nor does the video play.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">

<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="300">
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
    var firstVideo, secondVideo, videoSource
    var videoDiv;
    function eventWindowLoaded() {
        firstVideo = document.createElement("video");
        videoSource = document.createElement("source");
        firstVideo.appendChild(videoSource);
        //secondVideo = document.createElement("video");
        videoDiv = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(videoDiv);
        videoDiv.appendChild(firstVideo);
       //videoDiv.appendChild(secondVideo);
        videoDiv.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        var videoType = supportedVideoFormat(firstVideo);       
        if (videoType == "") {
            alert("no video support");
            return;
        }
        videoSource.setAttribute("src", "/Content/QualitySample." + videoType);
        videoSource.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
        firstVideo.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        firstVideo.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
        firstVideo.addEventListener("canplaythrough", videoLoaded, false);
        //secondVideo.setAttribute("src", "/Content/QualitySample." + videoType);
        //secondVideo.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        //secondVideo.addEventListener("canplaythrough", videoLoaded, false);


    }

    function supportedVideoFormat(video) {
        var returnExtension = "";
        if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4") == "probably" ||
       video.canPlayType("video/mp4") == "maybe") {
            returnExtension = "mp4";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/webm") == "probably" ||
   video.canPlayType("video/webm") == "maybe") {
        returnExtension = "webm";
    } else if (video.canPlayType("video/ogg") == "probably" ||
   video.canPlayType("video/ogg") == "maybe") {
        returnExtension = "ogg";
    }


    return returnExtension;

}

function canvasSupport() {
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}

function videoLoaded(event) {

    canvasApp();

}

function canvasApp() {

    if (!canvasSupport()) {
        return;
    }

    function drawScreen() {

        //Background
        context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
        //Box
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        context.strokeRect(5, 5, theCanvas.width - 10, theCanvas.height - 10);
        //video
        context.drawImage(firstVideo, 60, 50, 200, 200);
        //context.drawImage(secondVideo, 260, 50, 200, 200);

    }

    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    //firstVideo.load();
    firstVideo.play();
    //secondVideo.play();
    setInterval(drawScreen, 33);

}
```

}
when the page loads the video is displayed on the canvas and the video is loaded but no controls are active nor does it play.

Comment: Does it work for other video types?  If so, file a bug report with Chromium.  Also, I don't believe controls *should* appear when you copy a still image from a video element to a canvas.

Comment: And just to clarify, why aren't you just using the video element itself?  Is it just an experiment, or do you want to be able to capture the entire video frame-by-frame?  Or something else?

Comment: See my comment below.  Doesn't appear to function under .mp4, .webm or .ogv

Answer (score 1):

MP4 is a media file type.  However, MP4 can support any number of different Codecs.  Some Codecs are protected by patents, so Chrome might not be able to use certain Codecs.  Make sure the Codec of your video is supported.

See also: http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20028196-264.html

Edit: I mean "protected" in that Google doesn't want to pay the fees to support the codec, not that Chrome couldn't handle that codec.

Comment: This is a sample I was working off of. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/
Going there now there is an implementation of the same video in .mp4, .webm and .ogv.  Within Chrome, none of the three play.

Comment: Just tried that site... all are playing for me in Chrome, actually.

Comment: Weird.  All show the first frame and then get stuck in 19.0.1084.52

Comment: @Mike I am also facing a similar issue,If u had found any solution, please post it.